# Using C# to SaveAs Excel 2007 and up

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I included this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I would like to be able to open an Excel file XLSX and do a save it as a different file:

```
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(xlWorkBook.Path + @"\XMLCopy.xls",
                      Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet,
                      ,,
                      false,
                      false,
                      Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                      ,,,,);
```

There are missing parameters above, and I do not understand what to enter for them!

Here's my full code:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range range;

            string str;
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

**Question**: How can I save the Excel file with a different name/path using c# as above?

Comment: Type.Missing should do the trick (unless you are using .net 4 in which case you can omit missing parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Visual Studios 2010](http://humblecoder.co.uk/uncategorized/visual-studio-versions-net-versions-c-version-2) to properly use optional parameters in C#.

If you cannot use Visual Studios 2010 then Eddy's suggestion [Type.Missing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.missing%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should work.

When using methods with optional parameters (and not using Type.Missing) it is usually a good idea to use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) when calling the function.

---

Also, you should be aware of the limitations and quirks of optional parameters (though most of them should not affect you since you are not creating methods with optional parameters):

- http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/04/19/optional-parameters-in-c4-c3-and-vb-net-with-a-side-order-of-il-quirks/
- http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/06/17/c-optional-parameters---pros-and-pitfalls.aspx
- http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters/

It should be noted that I do not recommend creating methods with optional parameters.  Either overload the method or create a new object where the user can set the [object properties](http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/02/timesaver-aweso.html) before calling the method.